# Uploaded file does not come to the filebag of the request

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have a user profile screen which shows a user's information along with a profile picture. There I have a link called "Change Photo" which triggers a file input to upload a new image. Then I have a JS code to submit the form soon after the file input takes the image. But once the form is submitted, at my controller, when I dump my request, the filebag  is empty.

This is my .twig file

```
{% extends('base.html.twig') %}
{% block title %}Welcome- Open Rpoad Tolling!{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<style>
    body{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3931af, #00c6ff);
    }
    .emp-profile{
        padding: 3%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .profile-img{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .profile-img img{
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .profile-img .file {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: -20%;
        width: 70%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        background: #212529b8;
    }
    .profile-img .file input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .profile-head h5{
        color: #333;
    }
    .profile-head h6{
        color: #0062cc;
    }
    .profile-edit-btn{
        border: none;
        border-radius: 1.5rem;
        width: 70%;
        padding: 2%;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #6c757d;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .profile-edit-btn:hover{
                 color: #FFF;
                 background: rgb(240, 173, 78, 0.75);
                 /*border: 2px solid rgba(240, 173, 78, 0.75);*/
    }
    .proile-rating{
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #818182;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    .proile-rating span{
        color: #495057;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .profile-head .nav-tabs{
        margin-bottom:5%;
    }
    .profile-head .nav-tabs .nav-link{
        font-weight:600;
        border: none;
    }
    .profile-head .nav-tabs .nav-link.active{
        border: none;
        border-bottom:2px solid #0062cc;
    }
    .profile-work{
        padding: 14%;
        margin-top: -15%;
    }
    .profile-work p{
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #818182;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    .profile-work a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #495057;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .profile-work ul{
        list-style: none;
    }
    .profile-tab label{
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .profile-tab p{
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #0062cc;
    }
</style>


{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<div class="container emp-profile">
    <form action="{{ path('changeImage') }}" name="changeProfilePhoto" id="changeImageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <img src="{{ photoSrc }}" alt=""/>
                    <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="fileUploadButton">
                        Change Photo
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="profile-head">
                    <h5>
                        {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}
                    </h5>
                    <h6>
                        Web Developer and Designer
                    </h6>
                    <p class="proile-rating">RANKINGS : <span>8/10</span></p>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Timeline</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ editProfile }}';" class="profile-edit-btn" name="btnAddMore" >Edit Profile</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-work">
                    <p>WORK LINK</p>
                    <a href="">Website Link</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootsnipp Profile</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootply Profile</a>
                    <p>SKILLS</p>
                    <a href="">Web Designer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Web Developer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WordPress</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WooCommerce</a><br/>
                    <a href="">PHP, .Net</a><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>User Id</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Kshiti123</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Kshiti Ghelani</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>kshitighelani@gmail.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Phone</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>123 456 7890</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Profession</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Web Developer and Designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Experience</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Expert</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Hourly Rate</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>10$/hr</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Total Projects</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>230</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>English Level</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Expert</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Availability</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>6 months</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label>Your Bio</label><br/>
                                <p>Your detail description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="file" id="changeImageButton" name="file"/>
    </form>
</div>



<script>
    const changeImgButton = document.getElementById('changeImageButton');
    const fileUploadButton = document.getElementById('fileUploadButton');
    const formHome = document.getElementById('changeImageForm');
    changeImgButton.addEventListener("change",function () {

            formHome.submit();


    });fileUploadButton.addEventListener("click",function () {

        changeImgButton.click();


    });


</script>
{% endblock %}
```

// This is my controller

```
    /**
 * @Route("/changeImage", name="changeImage")
 * @param Request $request
 */

public function changeImage(Request $request){

    $file = $request->files->get('file');
    dump($request);die;
    if($file){
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('uploads_dir'), $fileName
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Open "Network" tab withing dev.tools in your browser and perform upload. Examine actual request body - do you see image inside it?